# A* search in java returning infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop, a-star

I have been at this for 2 hours and cannot for the life of me find out why this method is returning an infinite loop. I know this implementation is not the best in terms of efficiency, any suggestions for that are good too :)

Driver.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Driver {
    static Board b;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        while(init()){
            init();
        }

        System.out.println("Thanks for testing out the A* program");
    }

    private static boolean init(){
        System.out.println("Would you like to play? (\"y\",\"n\")");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = s.nextLine();

        if(!input.equals("y")){
            return false;
        }

        b = new Board(3,3);

        System.out.print(b.toString());

        while(getStartValue() == false){
            getStartValue();
        }

        while(getDestinationValue() == false){
            getDestinationValue();
        }

        System.out.print(b.toString());

        b.setHValueAllNodes();

        b.createPath(b.getStartPosition());
        System.out.print(b.toString());

        return true;
    }
    private static boolean getStartValue() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a starting X position");
        int startX = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter a starting Y position");
        int startY = s.nextInt();

        if(b.getBoard()[startX][startY].getStatus() == 'X'){
            System.out.println("Please enter a position that is not an obstacle");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            b.getBoard()[startX][startY].setStatus('S');
            b.setStartPosition(startX, startY);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static boolean getDestinationValue() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter an ending X position");
        int endX = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter a ending Y position");
        int endY = s.nextInt();

        if(b.getBoard()[endX][endY].getStatus() == 'X'){
            System.out.println("Please enter a position that is not an obstacle");
            return false;
        }
        else if(b.getBoard()[endX][endY].getStatus() == 'S'){
            System.out.println("Please enter a postition that is not the starting value");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            b.getBoard()[endX][endY].setStatus('E');
            b.setEndPosition(endX, endY);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Node.java

```
public class Node {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    //Controls if transversable
    private char status;

    //f = g+h
    private int f;
    private int g;
    private int h;

    private Node parent;

    Node(char status, int x, int y){
        this.status = status;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.g=0;
        this.h=0;
        this.f=0;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public char getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(char status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getF() {
        return f;
    }

    public void setF(int f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public int getG() {
        return g;
    }

    public void setG(int g) {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public int getH() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(int h) {
        this.h = h;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(this.getStatus() == 'O'){
            return "O (" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ", " + this.getH() + ", " + this.getG() + ", " +this.getF() + ")"; 
        }
        else if(this.getStatus() == 'S'){
            return "S (" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ")";
        }
        else if(this.getStatus() == 'E'){
            return "E (" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ")";
        }
        else{
            return "X (" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ")";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if( !(obj instanceof Node)) return false;

        Node nodeObj = (Node) obj;
        return (nodeObj.getX() == this.getX() && nodeObj.getY() == this.getY());
    }


}
```

Board.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class Board {
    private int length;
    private int width;
    private Node[][] board;
    private ArrayList<Node> openList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Node startPosition;
    private Node endPosition;

    public Node[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(Node[][] board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    Board(int length, int width){
        board = new Node[length][width];

        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int row=0; row < board.length; row++){
            for(int col=0; col < board[row].length; col++){

                int randomNum = rand.nextInt(10);

                if(randomNum == 0){
                    board[row][col] = new Node('X',row,col);
                }
                else{
                    board[row][col] = new Node('O',row,col);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Node getStartPosition() {
        return this.startPosition;
    }

    public void setStartPosition(int x, int y) {
        board[x][y].setStatus('S');
        board[x][y].setParent(null);
        startPosition = new Node('S', x, y);
    }

    public Node getEndPosition() {
        return endPosition;
    }

    public void setEndPosition(int x, int y) {
        board[x][y].setStatus('E');
        endPosition = new Node('E', x, y);
    }

    public void setHValueAllNodes(){
        for(int row=0; row < board.length; row++){
            for(int col=0; col < board[row].length; col++){
                int xDistance = Math.abs(endPosition.getX() - board[row][col].getX());
                int yDistance = Math.abs(endPosition.getY() - board[row][col].getY());
                board[row][col].setH(xDistance + yDistance);
            }
        }
    }

    public void createPath(Node n){
        Node minimum;
        System.out.println("RUNNING WITH NODE " + n.getX() + n.getY());

        //1. Add the starting square to open list
        if(n.getStatus() == 'S'){
            openList.add(n);
        }

        //d1. Stop when the open list is empty
        if(openList.isEmpty() ){
            return;
        }
        //d4. Add the target square to the closed list
        if(n.equals(endPosition)){
            return;
        }

        //2a. Find lowest F score in our list
        int index = 0;
        int indexMin = 0;
        minimum = openList.get(0);
        for(Node node: openList){
            if(node.getF() < minimum.getF()){
                minimum = node;
                indexMin = index;
            }
            index++;
        }       

        //2b. Switch minimum node to closed list    
        //Remove node from openlist 
        openList.remove(indexMin);

        //Add to close list
        closedList.add(minimum);

        //c. For each of the 8 squares adjacent to this square
        addToOpenList(minimum);

        createPath(minimum);

        System.out.println("OUR OPEN LIST CONTAINS: ");
        for(Node n1 : openList){
            System.out.print("X: " + n1.getX() + "Y: " + n1.getY());
        }
        System.out.println("OUR CLOSED LIST CONTAINS: ");
        for(Node n2 : closedList){
            System.out.print("X: " + n2.getX() + "Y: " + n2.getY());
        }
        System.out.println();   
}

private void addToOpenList(Node n) {
    boolean inClosedList = false;
    boolean inOpenList = false;
    for(int i= -1; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++){
            inClosedList = false;
            inOpenList = false;
            //c1. If it is not walkable or it is in closed list ignore it
            int xPos = n.getX() + i;
            int yPos = n.getY() + j;

            if(xPos == -1 || yPos == -1){
                System.out.println("OUR NODE IS OUT OF BOUNDS: " + "X: " + xPos + "Y: " + yPos);
            }
            else{
                for(Node node : closedList){
                    if(node.equals(board[xPos][yPos])){
                        inClosedList = true;
                        System.out.println("OUR NODE IS IN THE CLOSED LIST: " + "X: " + xPos + "Y: " + yPos);
                    }
                }
                if(inClosedList == false){
                    //c2. If it isnt on the open list, add it to the open list. Make the current square the parent of this square. Record F, G, H of the square
                    System.out.println("OUR NODE IS NOTTTTTTTT IN THE CLOSED LIST: " + "X: " + xPos + "Y: " + yPos);
                    int gCounter = (i + j == 1)? 10 : 14;
                    int g = n.getG() + gCounter;
                    int f = g + board[xPos][yPos].getH();

                    for(Node node1 : openList){
                        System.out.println("OUR NODE IN FOR LOOP: " + "X: " + xPos + "Y: " + yPos);
                        if(node1.equals(board[xPos][yPos])){
                            System.out.println("OUR NODE IS IN THE OPEN LIST: " + "X: " + xPos + "Y: " + yPos);
                            inOpenList = true;
                            //c3.If it is in the open list already, check to see if this path to the square is better, using g cost as the measure
                            if(g < board[xPos][yPos].getG()){
                                board[xPos][yPos].setG(g);
                                board[xPos][yPos].setF(f);
                                board[xPos][yPos].setParent(n);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(inOpenList == false){
                        System.out.println("WE ARE HERE WITH" + "X: " + xPos + "Y: " + yPos);
                        board[xPos][yPos].setG(g);
                        board[xPos][yPos].setF(f);
                        board[xPos][yPos].setParent(n);
                        openList.add(board[xPos][yPos]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        for(int row=0; row < board.length; row++){
            for(int col=0; col < board[row].length; col++){
                output += board[row][col].toString() + "\t";
            }
            output += "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }



}
```

Comment: why all your while loops are while(A()){A()}? it should be while(A());

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes at first sight, I don't know if my suggestions are semantically correct.

---

Mistakes:

---

wrong:

```
 while(init()){
        init();
    }
```

right:

```
 while(init());
```

---

wrong:

```
while(getStartValue() == false){
    getStartValue();
}

while(getDestinationValue() == false){
    getDestinationValue();
}
```

right:

```
 while(!getStartValue());
 while(!getDestinationValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in my createPath class...

I was recursively calling createPath instead of doing a while loop checking that the open list was null.